# Catalina update not showing

Tags: macos, software-update, catalina, beta

I installed MacOS 10.15 public beta when it came out and I've updated to a few other betas. Since Catalina update came out, I've not been able to install it because it doesn't show up. I've deleted the beta profile and I'm still not getting the update.[image: Settings -> Software Update]

Answer (score 2):

When transitioning from a beta to a release version of the OS, you won’t be able to do it via Software Update.  Instead, open App Store and install the release version from there.